# Using jquery "this" with a "selector"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, selector

I am getting up to speed with jquery and woudl like to know how I could write the following code so it's a bit more DRY and using $(this)

```
//Update Background Color
(function($) {
    //Find Background Colour
    var curColor = $('ul.product-categories li.current-item a').css('color');

    if($('ul.product-categories li').hasClass('current-item')) {
        //trying to use 'this' below but does not work
        //$(this).children('a').css({

        //This does work
        $('ul.product-categories li.current-item a').css({
            'background-color': curColor,
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    } else {
        $('ul.product-categories li.cat-item-11 a').css({
            'background-color': '#dd3c85',
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions on how to improve. I know it's probably something simple...

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason to use $(this) in that code. You should be using `curColor`

Comment: Why not set $('ul.product-categories li') as a variable, and then use .find() on the following variable when you need certain elements.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of how you should store a reference to the item so you dont have to keep using the jQuery selector over and over.

Also note its a good idea to put a "$" at the start of variables that reference a jQuery object as opposed to normal variables, makes it easier to see which is which

```
//Update Background Color
(function($) {

    //save a reference to the item
    var $item = $('ul.product-categories li.current-item a');

    //Find Background Colour
    var curColor = $item.css('color');

    if($item.hasClass('current-item')) {
        $item.css({
            'background-color': curColor,
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    } else {
        $item.css({
            'background-color': '#dd3c85',
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Many thanks. I just need to get into a better habit of storing as variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to 'cache' the DOM queries, to improve performance.

```
//Update Background Color
(function($) {
    //Find Background Colour
    var $categories = $('ul.product-categories');
    var $curr = $categories.find('li.current-item a');

    if(!$.isEmptyObject($curr)) {
        $curr.css({
            'background-color': $curr.css('color'),
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    } else {
        $categories.find('li.cat-item-11 a').css({
            'background-color': '#dd3c85',
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Many thanks. I just need to get into a better habit of storing as variables.